# How to load an angular application inside another angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, web

I have two angular application say A and B. Now in B application's One tab i want to **load entire application A**. How do i achieve this?

Please let me know how to achieve this functionality. Does angular has any special tag which i can use

Answer (score 6):

One solution to your problem might be to create the tag you are asking for yourself. I implemented Angular application A in Angular application B by a technique named web component or [Angular elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements) as stated above, see e.g. https://www.techiediaries.com/angular/angular-9-elements-web-components/

In the following steps a tag **shiny-app-a** is defined in application A which is used later on in application B by importing the JavaScript files of A into B and referencing them by the tag.

It works in the following environment:

- Angular CLI: 11.0.2
- Node: 12.16.1
- OS: win32 x64

The steps to make it run are:

### 1. Create application A

This application additionally needs the package @angular/elements.

#### 1.1. Create the skeleton of application A

```
$ ng new App-A
$ cd  App-A
$ ng add @angular/elements
```

#### 1.2. Apply changes to app.modules.ts to create the web component / element and define the corresponding tag shiny-app-a

My **app.modules.ts** looks like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
// import Injector
import { Injector, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
// import createCustomElement
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
  BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

  constructor(private injector: Injector){}

  ngDoBootstrap(){
    const el = createCustomElement(AppComponent, {injector:this.injector});
    // Here you define your new tag shiny-app-a
    customElements.define('shiny-app-a', el);
  }
 }
```

#### 1.3. Build project

```
$ ng build --prod --output-hashing none
```

This generates among others the files:

- runtime.js
- main.js
- polyfills.js

You will find them in the folder [...]\App-A\dist\App-A

#### 1.4. Test it

Run

```
$ ng serve
```

and see in the browser your newly built application A.

### 2. Create application B

Note: **no** @angular/elements is needed here.

#### 2.1. Create the skeleton of application B

```
$ ng new App-B
```

#### 2.2. Copy the files from application A to a folder accessible by application B

In this example I use the folder [...]/src/assets.

```
$ cd App-B/src/assets/
```

and copy the JavaScript from application A to this folder, i.e.:

- [...]/App-A/dist/App-A/main.js
- [...]/App-A/dist/App-A/polyfills.js
- [...]/App-A/dist/App-A/runtime.js

#### 2.3. Adapt source of application B to use the tag defined in step 1.

**2.3.1 Make custom elements known to application B in app.module.ts**

The crucial item to implement is **CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA**. My **app.modules.ts** of application B looks like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
// import CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  // add schemas
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**2.3.2 Load JavaScript from external source in app.component.ts**

The JavaScript files may also be loaded from any source. In this case the files are loaded by OnInit() from the [...]/assets folder. Thus my **app.component.ts** of application B looks like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'App-B';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadScript('/assets/runtime.js');
    this.loadScript('/assets/main.js');
    this.loadScript('/assets/polyfills.js');
  }

  public loadScript(url: string) {
    const body = <HTMLDivElement> document.body;
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.innerHTML = '';
    script.src = url;
    script.async = false;
    script.defer = true;
    body.appendChild(script);
  }
}
```

**2.3.3 Use tag in app.component.html**

Replace anything from the file **app.component.html** and just by:

```
<shiny-app-a></shiny-app-a>
```

#### 2.4. Test it

Run

```
$ ng serve
```

and see in the browser application A in application B.

Comment: This works partially for me. I well show the component of the second angular app, but it's in fullscreen so I don't show the base app. How can I fix it ?

Comment: I run into the problem that the compiler says: `Cannot find app-root` element. I tried using a prefix and even changing the app root element from my main project but always the same... :/

Answer (score 2):

You want something like MICRO front ends, build Application A as Angular custom element  (web component - Angular Elements), the output will be a script. Load this script in Application B. place the selector which you provided while creating a custom element in Micro App B where ever you want to load App A.

For  More read about Micro Front Ends ([Angular Elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements))

Please don't use iframe they become really difficult to manage, To know more read a little about Micro Front End with Angular there are lots of well-written blogs on the same.

Comment: in this examples thy are just loading one component.. I want to load entire app inside another app

Comment: Angular Element is not just a component, it's a complete application wrapped as a component.

Answer (score 0):

As Akshay mentioned you could use Angular Elements to expose your app A as a custom element and use it in app B.

In your case, you want to expose your AppComponent as a custom element.