# How to run two different Angular version apps in the same page

Tags: angular

New to Angular. I have a two separate Angular application with different Angular Versions. The old Angular application runs with Angular 9 however new runs with Angular 15. The requirement is to run new Angular app with old Angular App in such a way that the missing components in new Angular can be loaded from old Angular App.

Comment: as per your requirement, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to achieve this but it is possible.
below article would help you to understand the different solutions for this problem.

https://medium.com/swlh/multiple-angular-apps-on-a-single-page-9f49bc863177

Below thread is also relevant.

[How to load an angular application inside another angular application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60668161/how-to-load-an-angular-application-inside-another-angular-application)